# rspec association test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Still a bit new to rspec and can't get the following test to pass (problem area the             'it "should have the right treatings in the right order" do' block):

user_spec.rb

```
describe User do

    before do
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                        password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end

    describe "treating associations" do
        before { @user.save }
        let!(:older_treating) do
            FactoryGirl.create(:treating, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
        end
        let!(:newer_treating) do
            FactoryGirl.create(:treating, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
        end

        it "should have the right treatings in the right order" do          
            @user.sent_treatings.should == [newer_treating, older_treating]
            @user.received_treatings.should == [newer_treating, older_treating]
        end
    end

end
```

Based on my User and Treating models below, I know I need to have 'requestor' and 'requestee' embedded somewhere in the test, and I have tried different variations, but they all continue to fail. Here are the models:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
    has_secure_password

    has_many :sent_treatings, :foreign_key => "requestor_id", :class_name => "Treating"
    has_many :received_treatings, :foreign_key => "requestee_id", :class_name => "Treating"
end
```

treating.rb

```
class Treating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :intro, :proposed_date, :proposed_location

  validates :requestor_id, presence: true
  validates :requestee_id, presence: true

    belongs_to :requestor, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :requestee, class_name: "User"

    default_scope order: 'treatings.created_at DESC'

end
```

Here is my factories.rb file:

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :user do
        sequence(:name) { |n| "Person #{n}" }
        sequence(:email) { |n| "person_#{n}@example.com"}
        password "foobar"
        password_confirmation "foobar"

        factory :admin do
            admin true
        end
    end

    factory :treating do
    intro "Lorem ipsum"
    user
  end
end
```

Looking for an explanation of logic behind the appropriate code to fill in the '            it "should have the right treatings in the right order" do' block of the user_spec test. Thanks!

EDIT: sorry, forgot error message, here it is:

Failures:

1) User treating associations should have the right treatings in the right order
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:treating, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user=' for #<Treating:0x0000010385ec70>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:143:in`block (3 levels) in '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to override a field which doesn't exist.

You don't have user but a requestor or requestee. 
Try for example

```
FactoryGirl.create(:treating, requestor: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
```

Comment: thanks! i had tried that and received this error: 3) User treating associations should destroy associated treatings
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:requestor, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: requestor

Comment: Are you trying to create a user and asking for a requestor. Requestor is not defined in the factory, so it is not registered.

Comment: apologies, I meant: FactoryGirl.create(:treating, requestor: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)

Comment: unfortunately, with the above code in my user_spec, still getting similar error message in my terminal about a 'trait' not being registered:   1) User treating associations should have the right treatings in the right order
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create(:treating, requestor: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
     ArgumentError:
       Trait not registered: requestor